# Portfolio Press responsive CSS what if its not in style.css?

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I'm working with the Portfolio-Press theme in Wordress.  I've added a 980px wide file as the logo to give me a "banner" look.  Its a weathered wood plank look.  To take care of the margins to the left and right of this file that end up white, I've put a weathered plank file in the "branding" div, which is underneath the "logo" div, and given it a repeat-x so that it fills in the blanks no matter what size the screen is set at.  Works OK, except when the browser is sized below 750px.  There is a @media css call that activates which makes the background shift down about 100 px AND screws up the menu bar.  You'd think this would be easy to find and correct, but I'm a dummy. I've searched for this css call and can't find it in a real css file.  It must be generated by script or something.

The question is, is there anything that I can do about this without rewriting the javascript or whatever is writing this css?  And, if its javascript that has to be rewritten, where the heck is it?

You can view the site at

[www.bufalobobschalupas.com](http://bufalobobschalupas.com)

ITs easy to see the css changing if you run it with developer tools open, and choose the "branding" div, inside the "wrapper" div.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a line number as the css is all minified but this is your culprit;

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
   #branding {
     width: 46%
     height: auto;
   }
}
```

Remove the width and height attributes and it looks fine.

And you'll maybe want to add a media query at that screen size which removes the padding from `.col-width`

```
.col-width {
   padding: 0;
 }
```

EDIT: Realised I'd only half answered your questions.  The css file in question is;

http://chalupaholics.com/wp-content/w3tc/min/3b548d20.31cc2f.css

I don't know how that's being generated but I imagine by a plugin that's compiling the css into a single file for reduced page requests and minifying it.  I'm saying that because the css and JS is being added unusually high up in the order, even before the meta data.  Search through your install using Grep or [Astrogrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/) on Windows to find the source of this CSS before the plugin has acted on it and modify it there.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to find out how to add borders correctly to the thumbnails in Portfolio view, I found this post that describes the css elements I needed to update:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/theme-portfolio-press-cant-remove-the-grey-border-on-the-thumbnails

> "In your CSS file, find: #content img, img.thumbnail and remove
>   border: 1px solid #DDD;"

Then I override the style as I need in the header.php, directly above the closing **< /head>** tag. It is a bit of a hack, but I like it better than editing at the end of a long CSS file.  I figure this guarantees my CSS directive will be the last to be loaded and I will always sees my small modification at the top of the file.

Not sure if this helps, but it took me a bit of searching to figure out the CSS to edit.  I thought this might be a good place to share that find and how I was able to use it.